# How to create an EAN13 barcode generator, that gets the EAN as input?

Tags: android, generator, barcode, zxing, encode

I have to use the ZXing library, or any other lib that is apache2 (open source).
I created the core.jar lib. But i don't want to copy all the sources from the original ZXing project into my project. What should i use from the original ZXing into my project in such a way that i could encode and generate the EAN barcode to use after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code made it possible:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_FORMAT", "EAN_13");
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", "3800065711135");
startActivity(intent);
```